# AVMutableCompositon AVMutableCompositionTrack m4a problems

Tags: ios, ios5, aac, avmutablecomposition

I am able to successfully create a simple app that plays sound using the code below. The problem however is if I change the asset from being an mp3 to an m4a (with aac encoding). No sound is produced, yet the duration of the composition matches the length of the added sample.

```
NSError *error;

AVMutableComposition* composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
AVURLAsset* audioAsset1 = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/sample.mp3"] options:nil];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioTrack1 = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio 
                                                                  preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

[audioTrack1 insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset1.duration)
                     ofTrack:[[audioAsset1 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0]
                      atTime:kCMTimeZero
                       error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@", error);

playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:composition];

player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

[player play];
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up posting this question everywhere and ended up creating a bug report with apple.

How I solved the issue is to have a step at the start that downloads the m4a into the apps temp directory and then add it to the composition from there. Works like a charm.

I won't go into detailed code on how to do it but as my app makes use of the popular AFNetworking library, here is the key parts.

```
1: AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:songURLRequest];
2: NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"song.m4a"];
3: operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];
```

Line 1: Setup an AFHTTPRequestOperation
Line 2: Setup a local path as a string where the file will be saved
Line 3: Set the outputStream on the AFHTTPRequestOperation to the local path

Hope this helps someone in the future!